# Get window title and Application/Process name of all the visible application window processes in mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, applescript

Is there any way we can get the window title and its corresponding process name in mac.

Currently, I am only able to get the window title using AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events" to get the title of every window of (every process whose visible is true)
```

If we can do this via any electron API/node module that would also be great.

Basically I just want to get a list of active window title along with their process id/name

Comment: @CJK I tagged electron because I was using this for an electron app, and I couldn't find any other way other than AppleScript to get this done, but if there is any other way we can do this by any electron API, or using any node module it would be great

Answer (score 3):

I guess this all depends on what you're really trying to do...

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, will create a *list* of *visible processes* and *their windows titles* as a *list of lists* in `processNamesAndWindowTitlesLists`.

In other words, each *item* of `processNamesAndWindowTitlesLists` is a *list* containing a *process name* and its *windows titles* as a *list*.

For example, on my system at the present moment, `item 1 of processNamesAndWindowTitlesLists` is:

```
{"TextEdit", {"Untitled", "Untitled 2"}}
```

So, with each *item* in `processNamesAndWindowTitlesLists` its first *item* is the *process name* and the second *item* is a *list* of its *windows titles*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set tmpList to {}
set windowTitles to {}
set visibleProcesses to {}
set visibleProcessesWithWindows to {}
set processNamesAndWindowTitles to {}
set processNamesAndWindowTitlesLists to {}

tell application "System Events"
    set visibleProcesses to name of (every process whose visible is true)
    repeat with processName in visibleProcesses
        if (count windows of process processName) is not 0 then
            set end of visibleProcessesWithWindows to processName
        end if
    end repeat
    repeat with processName in visibleProcessesWithWindows
        set end of windowTitles to (name of every window of process processName)
        set end of tmpList to (processName as list) & windowTitles
        set end of processNamesAndWindowTitles to tmpList
        set windowTitles to {}
        set tmpList to {}
    end repeat
end tell

repeat with aItem in processNamesAndWindowTitles
    set end of processNamesAndWindowTitlesLists to item 1 of aItem
end repeat


return processNamesAndWindowTitlesLists
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>